Is there any way to standardize different text that represents the same thing?
I am collecting product data from different supermarket's website. But I found that each store uses different name to represent the product.
For example:



Product name
Store
Link




360° Toothbrush With Tongue And Cheek Cleaner
NoFrills
product link


MEDIUM TOOTHBRUSH, 360°
FoodBasics
product link



and I want to standardized this as "360° Toothbrush".
My approach is first try to tokenized the product name and then compare the similarity by cosine law. But I found that this is not the right direction as I am seeking the standarized name before flushing to database (in order to categorize the "same" product by the store).
Please find my testing script below (thanks ChatGPT!)
import torch
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel

def get_sentence_vector(text):
  
    # Initialize the tokenizer and model
    tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
    model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

    # Ensure the model is in evaluation mode
    model.eval()

    # Encode the text
    inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt')

    # Perform a forward pass without gradient calculation
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(**inputs)

    # Extract the last hidden state
    last_hidden_states = outputs.last_hidden_state

    # Aggregate the hidden states using mean pooling
    sentence_vector = torch.mean(last_hidden_states, dim=1)

    return sentence_vector


def cosine_similarity(vec1, vec2):
    # Calculate the cosine similarity
    cosine_sim = torch.nn.functional.cosine_similarity(vec1, vec2, dim=1)
    
    return cosine_sim.item() 


example_text = "360° Toothbrush With Tongue And Cheek Cleaner"
example_text_2 = "MEDIUM TOOTHBRUSH, 360°"
example_text_3 = "Hair Expertise Hyaluron Plump Shampoo, with Hyaluronic Acid"

vector = get_sentence_vector(example_text)
vector_2 = get_sentence_vector(example_text_2)
vector_3 = get_sentence_vector(example_text_3)

print(cosine_similarity(vector, vector_2)) # 0.8426903486251831
print(cosine_similarity(vector, vector_3)) # 0.7190334796905518
print(cosine_similarity(vector_2, vector_3)) # 0.622465193271637

The above approach indeed give me some sense, the same product gives higher similarity. But how to make use of this result to give a standardized name?

What you want to is called clustering it is often demonstrated using points in 2D space, but can be also applied to strings, as long as you are able to provide way to compute distance between any 2 strings. If you must use cosine similarity AT ANY PRICE then you should find https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22828/clustering-with-cosine-similarity useful

Thank you @Daweo, cosine similarity is not a must. For implementation of clustering, do i need to pre-define some regions? And then I can use the vectorized text to compute where the text in

Hi, you need to specify cutoff threshold for cosine similarity. For example all products with score 0.95 are considered the same. As a standard name you can use a name of any product in the group (or path names to smth like chatgpt/bert summarizer and ask it to generate standard name). There is also library dedupe https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe which helps to join/cluster similar entities together (it is widely used to find the same person in a database with Addresses). Usage of such libraries is a must because searches in large datasets could take insanely long time.

@eulerisgood depends on clustering algorithm, you might use vectorized versions to compute distance between them
